# Moving an index to a column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following multi-index dataframe in Pandas:

```
X    Y       val
bar  one    -0.007381
baz  four    0.210000
foo  two     1.314373
qux  one     0.716789
```

Assuming that the second level only has one entry for each entry of the first level (BTW what do you call a MultiIndex or dataframe with this property?): How can I move one of the indices (e.g. `Y`) to make it a **column**? i.e.

```
X     val       Y
bar  -0.007381  one
baz   0.210000  four
foo   1.314373  two
qux   0.716789  one
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following would make Y the column

```
df.reset_index(level='Y')
```

If you want to make X the column, try this

```
df.reset_index(level='X')
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the rationale behind specifying the **column** in `reset_index` as opposed to  specifying what I actually want as the **index**?

Comment: Column indices could be multi-level as well